# Can I set fence post concrete next to large rock?

Tags: concrete, fence, post, rock

I have holes dug for my fence posts about 3 feet deep, 12 inches wide for tubes and they will be about 6 feet high.

2 of the holes have a large rock in the way (partially). I can reach the depth for a portion of the hold but a section has a rock sticking out at the bottom.

My thought was to cut out a piece of the cardboard tube where the rock is, then pour gravel, then tube, then concrete with post.

I don't have the tools or equipment to break the rocks and was wondering if there'd be any issues or if the post will be just fine.

Again this is only for 2 of the 8 posts we have, 1 of those being the gate post at 6x6 rather than 4x4.

Thanks!

Comment: How much are the rocks above the proposed bottom of the footing? And are the two stands next to each other?

Comment: You're probably fine to just pour around the rocks, assuming that your posts fit. This is just a fence, after all. If you wanted to be fancy, you'd rent a rotary hammer, drill a hole in the rock, set rebar in with epoxy (such as Simpson Set XP) and make the rock a part of the anchor.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't anticipate any problem.

My concern is using tubes in the ground, but this might be a country specific thing.

We only use tubes to support concrete where it is out of the ground. We find the extra friction of the concrete filling the hole itself holds much better and resists rocking (when compared to loose-fill/backfill around a concreted tube).